# Explanation on code after if statement colon

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, syntax

Whilst I was learning pygame, I stumbled across a line of code that I did not understand:

```
if y == 0 or y == height-1: var1 *= -1
```

I understand what if statements are in python and the usage of logic gates, what I don't understand is the small piece of statement after the if statement:
"var1 *= 1"

Can someone explain this syntax? I do not understand the code and thought it would return a syntax error if we type anything beyond a colon.

Comment: This is just putting two statements on the same line, which is legal. Would you understand it if the `var1...` part was on the next line?

Comment: `x *= y` is equivalent to `x = x * y`.   There are some slight differences in implementation for some types, but that's probably nothing you need to worry about at this stage

Comment: Same effect: `var1 = -var1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually there is no rule that you cannot write something after a colon in Python. In fact, you could write multiple statements after an if condition as well, like: `if True: print("foo"); print("bar")`.

However for stylistic reasons generally it is recommended to write it in a new line after the colon. Exceptions might be when the content of the block is very simple and one line.

`*=` means to assign the variable on the left to the value of itself multiplied by the expression on the right.

Comment: Oh I see!, well that's helpful to know - could neaten up the code a bit. Thanks

Comment: The semicolon has its limits. Only *simple* statements can be joined with a semicolon. I'm somewhat surprised it survived into Python 3, and very much doubt it would be added if the language were being defined from scratch today.

Answer (score 1):

We can write stuff after colons. Another common thing is to use semicolon to chain operations or imports. But those syntax are highly discouraged for readability. I'd write it like this:

```
if (y == 0 or y == height-1):
    var1 *= -1
```

Or if you have more complex relations:

```
cond1 = (y == 0)         # explanation1
cond2 = (y == height-1)  # explanation2

if (cond1 or cond2):
    var1 *= -1
```

Comment: Just for understanding, can you give me an example of a chain operation?

Comment: @Blueboy90780 might be the wrong word. I thought of something like this on one row: `print("1");print("2");print("3")` ("chaining of operations")

Answer (score 0):

```
var *= -1
```

is equivalent to

```
var = var * (-1)
```

So it means that the sign of var will change .

---

```
if condition: statement
```

is equivalent to

```
if condition:
    statement
```

Comment: This is not what I meant, I'm asking the whole line in general

Answer (score 0):

In general

```
if condition is true:    
        statement
else:
    another statement
```

So,according to your statement:

```
if y == 0 or y == height-1:
    var = var * (-1)
```